# Retrieving audio file using Spring and XMLHttpRequest() results in window.URL.createObjectUrl is not a function error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to download an audio file using `XMLHttpRequest` from a Spring controller without any success.  There are numerous SO posts that describe different ways to do this but obviously I'm missing something. I realize I can just set the audio.src to an url without using AJAX, but for various reasons that won't meet the requirements for the site. I tested that approach and it does work which leads me to believe the controller is returning a valid file.

I've tried lots of different variations on the code below but even though I can see in  Firebug that the audio file appears to be returned correctly in the response I always run into the `window.URL.createObjectUrl` is not a function error.  I've gone through all of the javascript libraries and my own javascript and I can't find anywhere that `URL` was redefined to be something else.

I saw a post somewhere that this error may be returned if the blob is not well-formed - is there any way to check if that's the problem? Otherwise I'm stuck.

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAudio", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
public void getAudio(@RequestParam("audioId") Long audioId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //utility function that copies the audio file to the response output stream
    audioUtil.getNoAudioFile(audioId, response);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function getAudio() {
    var url = appContextPath + '/getAudio?audioId=1';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'audio/ogg'});
            var size = blob.size;    //this returns the correct # bytes
            var type = blob.type;    //this returns 'audio/ogg'
            var audio = $('.audioCtl').get(0);
            //variations I tried - none of them work
            //var url = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
            //var url = URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
            var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectUrl(blob);
            audio.src = url;
            audio.onload = function(evt) {
                (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectUrl(audio.src);
            }
            audio.play();
        };      
      };
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to remove any possibility that some other parts of the app were somehow causing this error so I took a basic Hello World app and added the controller method to retrieve the audio file and added the appropriate javascript. Same error. So then I found a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ysangkok/sJxXk/86/) for a .png file, added the appropriate code and it worked! Reworking my audio code I ended up with this:

```
var blob = this.response;           
$('.audioCtl').get(0).src=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var audio = $('.audioCtl').get(0);
audio.onload = function(evt) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectUrl(audio.src);
};
audio.play();
```

If I change it back to this, I get the error:

```
var blob = this.response;           
var audio = $('.audioCtl').get(0);
audio.src = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
audio.onload = function(evt) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectUrl(audio.src);
};
audio.play();
```

It didn't matter if I used `var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'audio/ogg'});` or `var blob = this.response;`.

I don't have a clue as to why the first one works and the second doesn't.  Anyone?

Comment: If you're testing in Chrome then `URL` needs to be `webkitURL` as this is still an experimental feature. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility) for more information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm testing in Firefox, but I also tried it in Chrome with webkitURL and got the same error.

Comment: I'm using ajax with Jquery, it works fine for me. if you'll explain better what you need to solve I'll be able to post a solution for you with Jquery.

Comment: @MosheArad I updated the javascript code with a bit more information. Everything works correctly until `createObjectUrl(blob)` which fails with the "not a function" error. If you have similar code that does work go ahead and post it as a solution and I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for a working Ajax example, so here it is:

**The controller:**

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    @ResponseBody
    public String register(@ModelAttribute GameUser user){
        System.out.println(user);
        return "Ajax call completion...";
    }
}
```

**I guess you're asking yourself what is GameUser:**

```
public class GameUser {

    private Long userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    //setter & getters
}
```

**Finally, my jQuery code:**

```
$(loadDomEvents);

function loadDomEvents(){
    $("#register").click(doAjaxCall);
}

function doAjaxCall(){
    var myData = $("#formAjax").serialize();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080";
    var dest = $("#urlDest").attr("href");

    $.ajax({ url:url + dest, data:myData, method:"POST", success:doSuccess});
    return false;
}

function doSuccess(text){
    console.log("success");
    alert(text);
    $("#ajaxAns").text(text);
}
```

**The JSP file:**

```
<a id="urlDest" class="hidden" href="<spring:url value="/register"/>"></a>
<p id="ajaxAns"></p>
<c:url value="/register" var="registerVar"/>
<form method="POST" action="${registerVar}" id="formAjax">
    <button type="submit" id="register">Register</button>
</form>
```

**Important issue:**

Between the form tag, you need to have fields that correspond to the fields of GameUser. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
```

the important part here is the name attribute with a value of userName with match the GameUser field `userName`, this how @ModelAttribute` does its form binding, by specifying matching name attributes.

Comment: Moshe, I think you misunderstood what the issue is. It is specifically with retrieving and playing an audio file using 'XMLHttpRequest()' and the 'window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob)' function throwing an error.  While I appreciate your AJAX example, it is unfortunately not relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: You asked me to post an Ajax example which I talked about earlier so I did.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not ask for an Ajax example. I asked if you have code similar to mine that includes `createObjectUrl(blob)` and doesn't fail on the "not a function" error I would try it. Please read my comment again.

Comment: Then don't post on Java and spring question belong completely to JavaScript. Your welcome.

Comment: For the record, I did not tag this question with Java - dhS added that tag. I included the Spring tag since I wasn't completely sure if the problem maybe wasn't with the @Controller method. The question was very explicit in the javascript function error and your answer does not include that function.